# Delete messages in service broker queue

Tags: sql-server, queue, service-broker

I'd like to clear my queue in SQL Server Management Studio, but I don't want to delete the whole queue just the content in the queue (the messages).

Comment: Do you want to clear all messages in all the queues in a database? The you should use `ALTER DATABASE ... SET NEW_BROKER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
while(1=1)
begin
    waitfor (
        receive top(1)
        conversation_group_id
        from dbo.yourQueue
    ), timeout 1000;

    if (@@rowcount = 0)
        break;
end
```

Comment: If you are using a [messaging pattern where the receiving endpoint cleans up the conversation](http://rusanu.com/2014/03/31/how-to-prevent-conversation-endpoint-leaks/), you may need to give special treatment to certain received messages (e.g. call END CONVERSATION on any messages whose type is EndOfStream).

Answer (score 56):

Just combining the two previous answers (by Ben and Jānis) for clarity.  This worked for me:

```
declare @c uniqueidentifier
while(1=1)
begin
    select top 1 @c = conversation_handle from dbo.queuename
    if (@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
    break
    end conversation @c with cleanup
end
```

Comment: Another good thing with this answer is that using `SELECT` instead of `RECEIVE` makes it possible to cleanup the queue even if it's disabled.

Comment: Worked for me when I changed the (@@ROWCOUNT=0) check with a (@c is null) condition. Thanks

Answer (score 10):

I would use [end conversation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177521.aspx)  (that will also remove all related messages from all queues) using statement:

```
End Conversation @c With CleanUp
```

if you just receive message, then you leave conversation open.
End Conversation With CleanUp is for specific situations only.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using SQL Server (starting with 2008) you can use RECEIVE

```
WHILE (0=0)
BEGIN
    RECEIVE * FROM dbo.YourQueue;
    IF (@@ROWCOUNT = 0) BREAK;
END
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue as the original poster, but I was needing to clear queues with
millions of messages (failed message queues, especially in non production environments that had not been checked for years).

The solution above would have worked, but was processing at less than 10 messages per minute.  By doing it in batches I was getting 30000 messages per minute.

The only noteworthy item in the code is `where validation = 'N'`.  This limits the conversation handles to the real messages.  There is a duplicate conversation handle for the response/error which gets removed by the `end conversation`.  Without this clause the script would still work, but generate a lot of errors in the output.

```
declare @conversationBatch table (convH uniqueidentifier)
declare @conversationHandle uniqueidentifier

declare convCursor cursor for
    select convH from @conversationBatch

insert into @conversationBatch
    select top 1000 conversation_handle  
      from dbo.queuename WITH (NOLOCK) 
     where validation = 'N'


while @@rowcount > 0
begin
    open convCursor
    fetch next from convCursor into @conversationHandle
    while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
    begin
        end conversation @conversationHandle with cleanup
        fetch next from convCursor into @conversationHandle
    end
    close convCursor

    delete from @conversationBatch
    insert into @conversationBatch
        select top 1000 conversation_handle  
          from dbo.queuename WITH (NOLOCK) 
         where validation = 'N'
    
 end

 deallocate convCursor
```

Answer (score -2):

```
while(1=1)
begin
    waitfor (
        receive top(1)
        conversation_group_id
        from kartokumaqueue2), timeout 1000;

        if(@@ROWCOUNT = 0) break;
end
```

Comment: This answer while potentially correct lacks context and would be improved by a code commentary stating why this answer works.  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer