# SQL Server Service Broker - Drop service

Tags: sql-server, service-broker

I have Service Broker queue infrastructure that I am using in my database for a few months. I realized that my `Initiator` queue has reached to 2 million records which are `EndDialog` messages. So I re-designed it thanks to this [link](http://rusanu.com/2006/04/06/fire-and-forget-good-for-the-military-but-not-for-service-broker-conversations/).

My problem is that I couldn't delete those 2 million records. I used the approach below as indicated in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19304940/2289430), and left the query executing. It executed for 20 hours until I canceled it.

```
declare @c uniqueidentifier
while(1=1)
begin
    select top 1 @c = conversation_handle from dbo.queuename
    if (@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
    break
    end conversation @c with cleanup
end
```

Now I am trying to drop Service and Queue but it seems it is gonna take lots of time again.

```
drop service initiatorService
drop queue initiatorQueue
```

Is there another way to delete immediately?

Queue Data;
[image]

Comment: have you got an example of your data please.  It doesnt have to be real, but a couple of lines of data with the condition that youre looking to remove will be great.  At the moment I can see why it would take some time because the code, on a while loop is not efficient and is doing a one by one taking up SQL Resource and you will probably find if you look at the event monitor that your job is suspended

Comment: @CodeWarrior I guess drop service is succesfully deleting messages code behind. After one hour now I saw that half of the messages has been deleted. The first code block, which uses `end conversation` is useless for my condition, I should use `waitfor receive..` I guess, I am not sure. I added the sample data.

Comment: have you tried a simple `delete from [table name] where message_type_name = 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sql.servicebroker/enddialog'` and then any other condition that you want to meet?

Comment: unfortunately, delete statements are not working on service broker queues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no shortcut to achieve your goal that I know of, unless you are willing to:

- Drop and recreate the database, or
- Reset all Service Broker data in all queues, including dialogs themselves, in that database (in this case, you might try to follow Remus' advise in the linked question - `ALTER DATABASE ... SET NEW_BROKER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;`)

Regarding your code, however, I would suggest using `receive` instead of `select`; otherwise you might get the same dialog multiple times. Also, you might want to distinguish `EndDialog` messages from any others if they occur in the queue.

Comment: You are right, I understood I can't melt messages filled up in queue without `receive` with code above, Your second option was what I did.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue where removing the services took really long. So long my SQL server ran out of memory and crashed. I first tried ending the dialog with the query you posted at the top, but that didn't help. In my case there were a lot of conversations created that were never closed. So although the queues were empty, there were still a lot conversations when I queryed sys.conversation_endpoints. I used the following script to clean up the conversations and after that I was able to delete it instantly.

**Note that below query will close all conversations, no matter the queue so you need to filter if you only want to delete a specific one**

```
declare @c uniqueidentifier
while(1=1)
begin
    select top 1 @c = conversation_handle from sys.conversation_endpoints
    if (@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
    break
    end conversation @c with cleanup
end
```